# screen placements on dwm

Tags: multi-monitor, dwm

I recently started using dwm, which is really nice, but I have a problem with regards to my multi monitor setup.

I have my monitors placed like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
|              2              ||                 3              |
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
|                             ||                                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
               ----------------------------------
               |                                |
               |                                |
               |                                |
               |                                |
               |                 1              |
               |                                |
               |                                |
               |                                |
               |                                |
               ----------------------------------
```

but when dragging my mouse from one screen to the next, I have to drag it from 1 -- 2 -- 3 through the right side of the screen with a lower number. This means that my screens are ordered as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                 1              ||              2              ||                 3              |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
|                                ||                             ||                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way for me to make dwm understand the correct placement of the screens?

Thanks for any help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is start dwm manually (e.g. using `startx`) and, before executing it in `.xinitrc` I have a `xrandr` command that sets up external monitors. `xrandr` supports position-related arguments of the form "display x is above display y" and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this allowed me to put monitor 1 below monitor 2. do you know how to handle the offset? such that the left part of monitor 1 is below monitor 2 and the right part of monitor 1 is below monitor 3?

Comment: See if the answer to this helps : https://superuser.com/questions/1245756/xrandr-set-offset-to-monitor

Comment: thanks a lot ;-)